# Install/Build gcc-4.4.6 on Ubuntu 12 and later

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-12.04

I am using ubuntu work station and my production environment is Centos 6.2 I used to use ubuntu 11.10 and I just install 4.4.6 coming with it and the compiled binary works perfectly under Centos 6.2 environment. Now I had to upgrade to ubuntu 12.04. Under Ubuntu 12.04, using apt-get I can only install gcc-4.4.7 which depends on glibc 2.15. The compiled binary no longer works under centos 6.2, with complains about incompatible glibc versions.

I got stuck on this problem for a long time. Could somebody advice what's the best way to get around this? Is there an easy way to install gcc 4.4.6 on ubuntu 12 and later? Or do I have to build gcc 4.4.6 from scratch? Is there an instruction for that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this steps to install gcc 4.4.6 :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.6
```